# How to manage group of Linksys SRW224G4 switches?

Tags: switch, linksys, network-management

I have 18 [Linksys SRW224G4](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9986/index.html) switches. As far as I know, they can be managed only one by one via web-interface that works only in IE. Is there any way to automate this process?
More specifically, now I need to enable portfast on all 100Mbit interfaces and apply one ACL to those ports. Can I do this in some automated way? Doing it manually on all 18 switches will be the worst nightmare I ever imagined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that these switches actually have CLI ([link](http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Switches/SRW-series-super-secret-CLI-mode/td-p/109959)). So all i need is to login via telnet and paste few commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TFTP server and the "File Management" functionality to configure one switch, modify the file, then load it onto other switches. Look on the "Maintenance" tab of the web interface. You'll have to edit the configuration for each switch, but at least you can do that with a script.

Comment: Hmm... I've found only 'Admin -> Save configuration' and resulting file looks like something binary. Also this line appeared in log:
`%COPY-I-FILECPY: Files Copy - source URL flash://startup-config.ber destination URL tftp://10.216.0.2/test.cfg`

Comment: looks like t can be managed via SNMP, but without specific MIB or some GUI/CLI tool it's almost impossible